# How does a ServerSocket accept a Socket after it has already connected?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I've realized you can write to a `Socket` when it hasn't been accepted by a `ServerSocket`. When I call `ServerSocket.accept()`, it automatically gets the connected `Socket` without it having to `connect()` again.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(0);
    int boundPort = serverSocket.getLocalPort();
    String host = serverSocket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName();

    Socket socket = new Socket(host, boundPort);
    write("Hi!"); // writes to socket's BufferedOutputStream

    Socket acceptedSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    read(); // reads and prints acceptedSocket's BufferedInputStream
}
```

Output:

```
Hi!
```

Not only is the `Socket` accepted, but the message is also outputted even though I wrote to the `OutputStream` before the `accept()`. I tried looking at the source code, but it was hard to follow. So my question is, what is the process for `accept()`? Is there a buffer of connected `Sockets` somewhere?

Also, how does writing to the `OutputStream` work? When exactly does the written data get sent over the network?

Thank you!

edit: Having received an answer to this question, I found another explanation from `man 2 accept` on Linux.

Comment: The TCP stack accepts and completes connections and places them on the backlog queue. At this point the peer can already read and write from/to the connection. `accept()` simply removes a connection from the queue, blocking while it is empty, and wraps a local socket around it.

Comment: That fixed all of my confusion. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is what is actually happening.

1. Opens/Binds Server Socket
2. Creates Socket A, Connect to Server Socket.  Socket A is half connected pending accept on the server.
3. Write data to the Socket A buffer; nothing is transmitted because it isn't actually connected.
4. Accept the Socket A on the Server Socket.
5. Buffered data in Socket A is transmitted to Server.
6. Transmitted data is read out on the Server.